# Xampp no image type for images with uppercase extension

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I was testing a code for a multiple upload file which the code is:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['files']) === true){
$files = $_FILES['files'];
echo '<pre>', print_r($files, true), '</pre>';
}
```

And the result I get is:

```
 Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 024.JPG
            [1] => 0241.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpCAC.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1851007
        )

)
```

Can someone please tell me why it's not showing results for images with uppercase extension?
I'm running this file in xampp 1.8.1 windows 7 64 bit

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem. To people who may be interested here's the code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['files']) === true){
$files = $_FILES['files'];
for ($x = 0; $x < count($files['name']); $x++) {
        $image = explode('.', $files['name'][$x]);
        $image_name = array_slice($image, -2, 1);
        $image_ext = strtolower(end($image));
      }

echo '<pre>', print_r($files, true), '</pre>';
}
```